# StreamReader IO Exception Not Enough Space on Disk

Tags: vb.net, file, text, streamreader, ioexception

I am trying to read 160 text files off of a network drive. I am using a `System.IO.StreamReader`. For some reason, when it gets to about the 22nd file, it throws the error:
*IO Exception was unhandled*. *There is not enough space on the disk*

Both my local disk and the network drive have more than enough space (these are small files), and I do not quite understand why a `StreamReader` would throw this exception (a `StreamWriter` would make more sense).

Here is some of my code:

```
'This sub is called 160 times (each file)
Private Sub readFile(filePath as String)
    'error gets thrown on this line
    Dim reader As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(filePath)
    'Reading through this file...
    '...
    '...
    reader.Close()
End Sub
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know if the exception occurs when you create the StreamReader ? Or when you call Read ? Also, what is the Exception Type ? `IOException` or more specific ? Also, you may want to use `Using` block as it automatically disposes the ressources when not used anymore...

Comment: It occurs when I create the StreamReader. It is an `IOException`. I'll look up the `Using` block - thanks.

Comment: Just tried `Using`. No luck. Thanks though.

Comment: Streams allocate resources which must be released and you are not allowing that because you do not dispose of them.  Anything which has a Dispose method should be used in a Using block.

Comment: Unfortunately, even in a Using block, it still did not work.

Answer (score -1):

I decided to try to read these files off of my local directory rather than off of the Network drive.

However, when I went to copy them (via Windows), I got the error: "There is not enough space on disk". The files are a total of 40mb and I have hundreds of gb free. After pressing "Try Again" 20 times, it slowly copied more and more over until complete. Strangely enough, it would copy the files over in batches of 42.

Then, I was able to read them from the local directory with no problem. It seems that the issue has to do with the Network drive.

My programmatic solution was to try to copy them over until they were all copied (which took about a minute, usually).

```
 'we start by copying all the files to a local drive. Since reading off the M: drive always throws lame exceptions...
 For Each f As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(fileDirectory)
     While (My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(toCopyTofileName)) = False
         Try
             My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(f, toCopyTofileName)
         Catch ex As Exception
             Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
         End Try
     End While
 Next
```

For now, the `Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)` is fine (I only retry every second), but I think I'll switch it to a `Timer` or something. I should also add a max time out limit.